# Как в Python строку разбить на 2 строки и каждую присвоить отдельной переменной?

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

Сама задача:Дана строка. Разрежьте ее на две равные части (если длина строки — четная, а если длина строки нечетная, то длина первой части должна быть на один символ больше). Переставьте эти две части местами, результат запишите в новую строку и выведите на экран.

```
Sample Input 2:

Hello
Sample Output 2:

loHel
```

Answer (score 1):

Конкретно для этой задачи можно через срезы:

```
s = input()
half = len(s) // 2 + len(s) % 2
print(s[half:] + s[:half])
```

Comment: Можно так: `half = len(s) - len(s) // 2`